# Django ORM and python gRPC not playing nicely with Django TestCase

Tags: python, django, grpc

Been stuck for a while, appreciate any insight here.

We're a kubernetes shop that runs grpc for our microservices. Recently I've been trying to use Django ORM with grpc for a new project. I'm trying to write unittests that hit the gRPC endpoints, and verify that data has been correctly stored into the DB.

The endpoint I'm hitting does the following:

1. Does a lookup based on the request (think of this like an authentication step)
2. Uses the result of the lookup + the request to create a new ORM object.
3. Saves that ORM object.

In order to test this, in my unittest I first pre-load some data into the DB during the `setUp` method, and then run the rest of the test. This to ensure that step (1) works as intended. **The issue I'm seeing - inside of the gRPC method, it doesn't find this preloaded data. However, inside the unittest I'm able to verify that the data exists.**

To further debug, I also printed out the "DATABASES" setting from my settings.py file, and verified that it's what I expect - it points to a local sqlite table (my unittest is also pointing to this same sqlite file).

What's weird is that if I preload data in the unittest and directly call some function outside of gRPC stub, it works fine.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Some code examples:

**gRPC FooService:**

```
from django.db import transaction

class FooService(FooServicer):
    @transaction.atomic
    def Create(self, request: CreateRequest, context):
      account = lookup_account(request) # Fails here - can't find account
      # ... does other stuff with account.
```

**unittest**

```
from django.test import TestCase

class FooServiceTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.server = grpc.server(ThreadPoolExecutor())
        foo_service_pb2_grpc.add_FooServicer_to_server(
            FooService(),
            self.server,
        )
        SERVICE_NAMES = (
            foo_service_pb2.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name[
                "FooService"
            ].full_name,
            reflection.SERVICE_NAME,
        )
        reflection.enable_server_reflection(SERVICE_NAMES, self.server)
        port = self.server.add_insecure_port("[::]:50051")
        self.server.start()
        channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:%d" % port)
        self._client = foo_service_pb2_grpc.FooServiceStub(
            channel
        )
        self._account_id = "1234"
        self._account = cdb.Account.objects.create(
            id=self._account_id,
            name="Bob"
        )

    def test_create(self):
      # If I check cdb.Account.objects.all() here, it shows 'Bob' account
      
      self._client.Create(CreateRequest(account_id="1234")
      # place expectations on ORM objects created.
```

**Update** - I found a workaround by not using Django TestCase, and instead using unittest.TestCase. Hopefully this won't bite me later. Still curious if anyone knows how to make this work with Django TestCase